# Why does the system slow down , upon resuming from Hibernation

Tags: windows, login, hibernate, remote-shutdown

I am using windows xp sp2 in an Quad core machine , with 3GB RAM . Each time when i log into my system after hibernation , it takes almost 5 to 10 mins to resume perfectly. Am i missing any configuration / setting changes .?

Are there any tweaks to get around this.?

Can someone help me on this .?

thanks,

vijay.

Comment: [This superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/48088/very-slow-after-hibernation) seems to cover the same ground.  In summary: Windows XP hibernation isn't great to start with, but there may be ways to tweak it, like making sure the hibernation file is not fragmented.

Comment: One of the first orders of business I always have after installing a machine is configuring the power settings to never hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a slow HD that slows everything down? You may want to do some benchmarks of you HD to see if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen every time you resume, or only, for example, after being left hibernating for a  long period (eg overnight)?

If the latter, then it is possible that some task is being triggered, eg anti-virus update or scan.